# How to publish pod to jfrog Artifactory?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, artifactory, podspec, jfrog-cli

I have a framework project written in Objective C that i want to publish on JFrog Artifactory.

My .podspec file is like this

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Name'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'summry'

  s.description      = <<-DESC
  description
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'homepage'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'user' => 'email' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'url.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '11.4'
  s.source_files = 'Name/*{.h}','Name/**/*{.h}'
  s.dependency "AFNetworking"

  end
```

it is working fine if i define something like this in my Podfile

```
pod ‘Name’,:git =>'url.git', :tag=>'0.0.1'
```

but the requirement is to publish this framework on JFrog and fetch from there, in JFrog video tutorial they are saying to upload project in tar.gz form and it will generate podspec file in Artifactory but its not happening in my case.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is the repository type you are using is cocoapods?

Comment: yes it is cocoapods lib

Comment: are you using the [plugin](https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoapods-art)? did you follow the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/CocoaPods+Repositories)?

Comment: @danf yes i'm using the cocoapod-art plugin and also i'm following the doc as i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: If the podspec file is not being generated in the .pod folder on the local repo then perhaps some error prevented the index from doing its job, post your log around the time of deployment

Comment: @danf sorry, i don't have access of log as i'm doing it in company premises

Comment: Really hard to go on without the logs.. I suggest you approach JFrog support so they can help you retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty line at the beginning and the end of the .podspec file. This somehow fixed the problem for me.

Also make sure your .podspec file passes all tests of `pod spec lint Name.podspec`